# Overloading operator-, operator<, and operator >

Tags: c++, list, stl, operator-overloading, biginteger

So, I'm very new to operator overloading and I cannot get the syntax for the operator-, operator>, and operator< down.

I was given the operator+ code for my code and it's difficult for me to change it for the operator- function. I am also getting lots of errors for my operator< function, but not my operator> function, which is basically the same.

If you could either shed some light on how to do this and/or provide me links for more help, that would be greatly appreciated.

This is what I have so far:

(As you can see I only copied and pasted the operator+ into my operator- to try and reason with it)

BigInt.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "BigInt.h"

using namespace std;

BigInt BigInt::operator+(BigInt operand)
{
    int carry = 0;
    int sum;
    BigInt result;
    list<int>::reverse_iterator rit1 = number.rbegin();
    list<int>::reverse_iterator rit2 = operand.number.rbegin();
    while ( (rit1 != number.rend()) || (rit2 != operand.number.rend()) )
    {
        sum = 0;

        if (rit1 != number.rend())
        {
            sum += *rit1;
            rit1++;
        }

        if (rit2 != operand.number.rend())
        {
            sum += *rit2;
            rit2++;
        }

        sum += carry;
        result.number.push_front(sum % 10);
        carry = sum / 10;
    }

    if (carry > 0)
        result.number.push_front(carry);

    return result;
}

void BigInt::display(ostream & out)
{
    for (list<int>::iterator it = number.begin(); it != number.end(); it++)
    {
        cout << *it;
    }

    cout << endl;
}


void BigInt::read(istream & in)
{
    string input;

    cin >> input;

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); ++i)
    {
            int x = input.at(i);
            int y = char(x) - char('0');
            number.push_back(y);
    }



}

bool BigInt::operator<(BigInt operand)
{
    list<int>::reverse_iterator rit1 = number.rbegin();
    list<int>::reverse_iterator rit2 = operand.number.rbegin();
    int count1 = 0, count2 = 0;
    bool check;
    while ( (rit1 != number.rend()) || (rit2 != operand.number.rend()) )
    {
        if (rit1 > rit2)
        {
            count1++;
            rit1++;
            rit2++;
        }
        else if (rit2 > rit1)
        {
            count2++;
            rit1++;
            rit2++;
        }
        else
        {
            rit1++;
            rit2++;
        }

    }
    if(count1 < count2)
    {
        check = true;
    }
    else
    {
        check = false;
    }

    return check;
}

bool BigInt::operator>(BigInt operand)
{
    list<int>::reverse_iterator rit1 = number.rbegin();
    list<int>::reverse_iterator rit2 = operand.number.rbegin();
    int count1 = 0, count2 = 0;
    while ( (rit1 != number.rend()) || (rit2 != operand.number.rend()) )
    {
        if (rit1 > rit2)
        {
            count1++;
            rit1++;
            rit2++;
        }
        else if (rit2 > rit1)
        {
            count2++;
            rit1++;
            rit2++;
        }
        else
        {
            rit1++;
            rit2++;
        }

    }
    if( count1 > count2)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }


}

bool BigInt::operator==(BigInt operand)
{
    list<int>::reverse_iterator rit1 = number.rbegin();
    list<int>::reverse_iterator rit2 = operand.number.rbegin();


    do
    {
        rit1++;
        rit2++;
    }
    while(rit1 == rit2);

    return false;

}

BigInt BigInt::operator-(BigInt operand)
{
    int carry = 0;
    int sum;
    BigInt result;
    list<int>::reverse_iterator rit1 = number.rbegin();
    list<int>::reverse_iterator rit2 = operand.number.rbegin();
    while ( (rit1 != number.rend()) || (rit2 != operand.number.rend()) )
    {
        sum = 0;

        if (rit1 != number.rend())
        {
            sum += *rit1;
            rit1++;
        }

        if (rit2 != operand.number.rend())
        {
            sum += *rit2;
            rit2++;
        }

        sum += carry;
        result.number.push_front(sum % 10);
        carry = sum / 10;
    }

    if (carry > 0)
        result.number.push_front(carry);

    return result;
}
```

BigInt.h

```
#include <list> 
using namespace std; 

class BigInt 
{ 
public: 
BigInt() {}; 
void read(istream & in); 
void display(ostream & out); 
BigInt operator+(BigInt operand); //overloading operator 
BigInt operator-(BigInt operand); //subtraction 
bool operator<(BigInt operand); 
bool operator>(BigInt operand); 
bool operator==(BigInt operand);
list<int> number; //using STL list 
};
```

I have nothing in my main.cpp yet.

Hope you can help me! Thanks!

EDIT!!!:

I forgot to list my errors for my operator< function:

```
Error   10  error C2676: binary '<' : 'std::_List_iterator<_Mylist>' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility 1014
Error   4   error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const _Elem *,const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const _Elem *' from 'std::_List_iterator<_Mylist>' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility 1014
Error   8   error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &,const std::_Revranit<_RanIt2,_Base2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &' from 'std::_List_iterator<_Mylist>'    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility 1014
Error   3   error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &,const _Elem *)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &' from 'std::_List_iterator<_Mylist>'   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility 1014
Error   5   error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &,const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &' from 'std::_List_iterator<_Mylist>' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility 1014
Error   2   error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::list<_Ty,_Alloc> &,const std::list<_Ty,_Alloc> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::list<_Ty,_Alloc> &' from 'std::_List_iterator<_Mylist>'   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility 1014
Error   6   error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::move_iterator<_RanIt> &,const std::move_iterator<_RanIt2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::move_iterator<_RanIt> &' from 'std::_List_iterator<_Mylist>'   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility 1014
Error   9   error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &,const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &' from 'std::_List_iterator<_Mylist>'  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility 1014
Error   7   error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &,const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &' from 'std::_List_iterator<_Mylist>'  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility 1014
```

Comment: It's not clear what the issues is here.  If you know how to implement `operator+`, what is the difficulty in implementing `operator-`?

Comment: I would start with changing the `||` in your `while` to `&&`. If this does what I think it does, that logical operator is incorrect as-written.

Comment: I'm confused on how to modify the operator+ for operator-. Is there very little modification from operator+ to operator-?

Comment: @WhozCraig, that's part of the code my professor gave me. I figured it was correct.

Comment: The problem with your `<` operator doesn't seem to be with the actual operator function but *how you call it*. You call it with an *iterator* not an `BigInt` instance. Remember that you have to use the dereference operator `*` to get what the iterator "points" to.

Comment: I can almost assure you (without testing) that you'd notice a significant speedup if you switched to `std::vector` from `std::list`. Go ahead and try a few million additions with either one.

Comment: @chris, I have to use a list for this assignment, otherwise I would without any hesitation use  std::vector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if (rit1 > rit2)` should be `if (*rit1 > *rit2)` as you want to compare the contents of the iterators not the iterator themself.

Comment: That solved my biggest error. Thank you.